# Set ggplot2 label background color

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have this bar plot

```
group = c("A","A","B","B")
value = c(25,-75,-40,-76)
day = c(1,2,1,2)
dat = data.frame(group = group , value = value, day = day)
dat
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=factor(group), y=value, fill=factor(day))) +
   geom_bar( stat="identity", position="dodge")+
   geom_label(aes(label =round(value,0),fill="white"),
   colour = "black", position= position_dodge(width=1))
```

I'd like the lables to be white backgroud with black font but when I add `fill="white"` the plot is incorrect. The labels do not have white background with black font.

notice here without the `fill="white"` the plot looks good. I just want to change label background and font

```
group = c("A","A","B","B")
value = c(25,-75,-40,-76)
day = c(1,2,1,2)
dat = data.frame(group = group , value = value, day = day)

ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=factor(group), y=value, fill=factor(day))) +
  geom_bar( stat="identity", position="dodge")+
  geom_label(aes(label =round(value,0)),colour = "black", 
    position= position_dodge(width=1))
```

**ALSO NOTE**

If I move `fill="white"` outside the `aes()` then the labels are not over the bars but stacked on one another. i.e. it negates the effect of `position=position_dodge(width=1)` and I need the labels over the bars

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make two changes:

1. Move `fill = factor(day)` into `aes()` within the `geom_bar`
2. Set `group = factor(day)` in your `geom_label`

As shown here:

```
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=factor(group), y=value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = factor(day)), stat="identity", position="dodge")+
  geom_label(aes(label =round(value,0), group = factor(day)),colour = "black", position= position_dodge(width=1))
```

[image]

Comment: If I move fill="white" outside the aes then the labels are not over the bars but stacked on one another. i.e. it negates the effect of position=position_dodge(width=1) and I need the labels over the bars

Comment: @user3022875 See fix (with #2)

Comment: Thank you......one more questions --- how would you now change the background and font.....lets say you wanted green background and blue font. I am asking beacause when I put fill=green int he geom_label(aes(...fill="green")) I get an error...Thank you

Comment: @user3022875 Put `fill = "green"` outside of the aes, and change your `colour` to "blue". e.g. `geom_label(aes(label =round(value,0), group = factor(day)), fill = "green", colour = "blue", position= position_dodge(width=1))`