# How to draw boxes/borders around x or y axis labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, border, axes

Is there a way in R to draw boxes/borders around x or y axis labels, possibly angled labels?

I've been using `ggplot` to create tile charts and found code that places around labels in the data itself (through `geom_label`: [Set ggplot2 label background color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39514394/set-ggplot2-label-background-color])  but not around labels in the axes themselves.

Chart Example:

[image]

Answer (score 7):

```
library(grid)

element_custom <- function() {
  structure(list(), class = c("element_custom", "element_text"))
}

element_grob.element_custom <- function(element, label="", ...)  {
  tg <- textGrob(label)
  padding <- unit(1,"line")
  rg <- rectGrob(width=grobWidth(tg)+padding, height=grobHeight(tg)+padding)
  gTree(children=gList(rg, tg), height=grobHeight(tg) + padding, cl="custom_axis")
}

heightDetails.custom_axis <- function(x) x$height + unit(2,"mm") # fudge

ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_line() + 
  labs(x= "Axis title")+
  (theme_grey() %+replace% theme(axis.title.x = element_custom()))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you baptiste for the quick reply. I'm a bit new to this so bear with me. I added a chart example to my posting above to provide some more context around what I need. I managed to get a tile chart like the one in the posted picture but I'm having a hard time drawing black borders around the x and y axes labels not titles(i.e. "Category1",..."Category 5" and "Type A", "Type D").                                                                                                                                                 Chart Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj7KF.jpg

Comment: Hi again baptiste and thank you for your answer. I think the code you provided can be generalized to what I need. Just don't know enough about grobs and grids to be able to apply it to axis.text.x and axis.text.y (which contain multiple labels), not to mention drawing angled borders around the x axis category labels at the top of the figure. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks.