# Is it possible to add border with border radius to x-axis title?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
library(ggplot2)

data <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1))
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "X-Axis Title", y = "Y-Axis Title") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, color = "black", face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.2, angle = 0))
```

Here is a basic `ggplot` with an X-Axis. We are attempting to create an X-Axis that looks something like:

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: why was this question immediately closed? it is not a duplicate. the other question linked is related to rounded corners on the entire graph, has nothing to do with a border with radius around the X axis.

Comment: Related to  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123684/how-to-draw-boxes-borders-around-x-or-y-axis-labels

Comment: This looks helpful, yes. Not an exact duplicate though. In this question, in the solution, the border is not rounded, but it looks like this question will still help us out as it involves adding a border around the x-axis title.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't dupe tagged it.   I think it got tagged before I commented

Comment: Your linked question is helpful. The linked question at the top of the posting `Rounded corners in ggplot2` is not as helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  ... + 
theme(axis.title.x = ggtext::element_textbox(linetype = 1, 
                                             r = grid::unit(10, "pt"),
                                             padding = margin(5, 10, 5, 10)))
```

[image]

Comment: clean, simple, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Another potential option is to use grid's [roundrectGrob](https://rdrr.io/r/grid/grid.roundrect.html):

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(grid)

element_custom <- function() {
  structure(list(), class = c("element_custom", "element_text"))
}

element_grob.element_custom <- function(element, label="", ...)  {
  tg <- textGrob(label)
  padding <- unit(1,"line")
  rg <- roundrectGrob(width=grobWidth(tg)+padding,
                      height=grobHeight(tg)+padding,
                      r = unit(0.75, "line"))
  gTree(children=gList(rg, tg), height=grobHeight(tg) + padding, cl="custom_axis")
}

heightDetails.custom_axis <- function(x) x$height + unit(2,"mm")

data <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1))

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(x = "X-Axis Title", y = "Y-Axis Title") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 12, color = "black", face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, vjust = -0.2, angle = 0)) +
  (theme_grey() %+replace% theme(axis.title.x = element_custom()))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Or, perhaps @Teunbrand has a function in the [elementalist package](https://github.com/teunbrand/elementalist) (worth a look).